# how to link two datepickes so that one's date cannot be greater or less then others'

Tags: wpf, datepicker

I am programming in WPF and in having an interface where Manufacturing date and Expiry date are two date pickers. How can I set my expiry date Date picker to select date only greater then mfg date?

Comment: Can you show some code ?

Answer (score 0):

The WPF datepicker doesn't have a minimum date property unfortunately, although it does have a DisplayDateStart dependency property. Within the calendar pop-up part of a datepicker control, this property hides dates prior to the assigned value.

However, users will be still be able to enter any expiry date using the textbox part of the datepicker. In order to handle this, you'll need to validate the SelectedDate properties of both datepickers.

I've attached code which does both (for the purpose of this question, I have assumed you're not using MVVM - if you are let me know):

Firstly, in XAML, the DisplayDateStart dependency property of the expiry datepicker is bound to the SelectedDate dependency property of the manufacturing datepicker (thus hiding invalid dates in the expiry datepicker calendar pop-up). As your requirement states "only greater than mfg date" a value converter is required to return the day after the manufacturing day.

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <yournamespace:NextDayConverter x:Key="NextDayConverter" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <DatePicker x:Name="ManufacturingDatePicker"
                SelectedDateChanged="OnSelectedDateChanged" />
    <DatePicker x:Name="ExpiryDatePicker"
                SelectedDateChanged="OnSelectedDateChanged"
                DisplayDateStart="{Binding 
                                   ElementName=ManufacturingDatePicker,
                                   Path=SelectedDate,
                                   Converter={StaticResource NextDayConverter}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

The NextDayConverter is detailed below:

```
namespace YourNamespace
{
    using System;
    using System.Globalization;
    using System.Windows.Data;

    public sealed class NextDayConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            if (value != null)
            {
                DateTime manufacturingDate = (DateTime)value;
                DateTime minimumExpiryDate = manufacturingDate.AddDays(1);
                return minimumExpiryDate;
            }
            return Binding.DoNothing;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Secondly, in code behind, there's a handler for the SelectedDateChanged event of both datepickers. The validation code in here sets the expiry date to the manufacturing date if the user enters an invalid expiry date (i.e. prior or equal to the manufacturing date).

```
private void OnSelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (ManufacturingDatePicker.SelectedDate.HasValue &&
        ExpiryDatePicker.SelectedDate.HasValue &&
        ExpiryDatePicker.SelectedDate <= ManufacturingDatePicker.SelectedDate)
    {
        ExpiryDatePicker.SelectedDate = ManufacturingDatePicker.SelectedDate.Value.AddDays(1);
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.